# How to completely delete recurring event instance?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

If you create a recurring event in google calendar, you actually create one single event (parent) with recurrence rule, others are just **virtually added**. Once you move any of those virtuals, it gets saved as instance and you can **edit it in any way** you like **without affecting the parent** event itself.

If you edit that instance to match its parent, it gets **deleted** and replaced with the virtual one once again. (No need to keep instance which is no different from the parent event, right?)

I'm doing the same in my application. However, when I'm trying to do so using google-php-api-client, the only option to delete something, is to set the **event status** as **'cancelled'** which will make the instance deleted.

My question is:

**How to delete (or reset) the instances without the need of updating them one by one to match its parent?**

EDIT: Forgot to mention why do I need this and what am I trying to achieve.

Basically, if you edit an instance, Google will ask you whether you want to edit **"Only this"**, **"Following"**, or **"All"** of the recurring events. If you select "Following", google will **throw away** everything related to the parent event from this date (`where original_start > date`), modify its rule to **set `UNTIL` rule with the date of instance being edited** and pass its old rule to newly created event with starting time same as the date of this particular instance.

Since I know of no method, how to delete multiple events matching some condition. The only way I could figure this out, is to select all of those, and update them one by one, which could be a bit of problem since you can:

1. Create recurring event with recurrence-end unspecified
2. Decide to modify all following events

Comment: If you edit an instance, then it wont be shown as an instance to the recurring event. If you try events.list with single='true', the changed instance wont show up. If you want to delete all the instances including parent, then in events.delete https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete , you should give recurring event Id (which you will get from events.list). This deletes the entire event with all the instances. Let me know if your scenario is different.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I've edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to delete that matches with particular condition. Even though you change the instances of recurring event, recurring event ID is same as parent.